# How can I change the position of the default "grip" in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to use the basic grip. but I don't see where I could change its position. Now if you look my picture you can see I disabled the borders and gave some shadows to the main rectangle. I would like to keep it that way.

[image: screenshot]

I wonder if there is a simple modification next to this "ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"

Code:

```
<Window x:Class="Serenity.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Serenity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1100" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="{x:Null}" MinWidth="720" MinHeight="480" Icon="Images/CloseBlack.png" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
<Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="MainTable" Fill="#FF1A1A1A" Margin="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1.0">
        <Rectangle.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect x:Name="Shadow" BlurRadius="13" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Black"/>
        </Rectangle.Effect>
    </Rectangle>
    <Button x:Name="Website" Content="Google" Margin="0,0,38,38" Click="button_Click" Background="#FF48484A" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" AutomationProperties.HelpText="You will close the program." Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="99"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="TitleBar" Fill="#FF2D2D30" Height="43" Margin="10,10,10,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDown="TitleBar_MouseDown"/>
    <Button x:Name="CloseB" Content="Exit" Margin="0,18,19,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.25,1.45" Click="CloseB_Click" Background="#FF48484A" OpacityMask="Black" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.resizegrip(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have tried and succeeded

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ResizeGrip}">
       <Setter Property="Margin"  Value="25"/>
</Style>
```